# Listen queue for multi threaded TCP server

Tags: tcp, listen

What is the significance of a listen queue(second argument in listen call) in a multi threaded TCP server?

It's a little confusing because why do we need a queue, when we have multiple threads to deal with different clients?

Answer (score 2):

From MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms739168(v=vs.85).aspx

> A value for the backlog of SOMAXCONN is a special constant that instructs the underlying service provider responsible for socket s to set the length of the queue of pending connections to a maximum reasonable value.
>
> On Windows Sockets 2, this maximum value defaults to a large value (typically several hundred or more). When calling the listen function in a Bluetooth application, it is strongly recommended that a much lower value be used for the backlog parameter (typically 2 to 4), since only a few client connections are accepted. This reduces the system resources that are allocated for use by the listening socket. This same recommendation applies to other network applications that expect only a few client connections.
>
> The listen function is typically used by servers that can have more than one connection request at a time. If a connection request arrives and the queue is full, the client will receive an error with an indication of WSAECONNREFUSED.

The fact that the TCP server is multi-threaded isn't relevant since this queue is outside of the application space i.e. between the OS and the application.

Answer (score 1):

To understand the concept; consider the following example,

You know that TCP does the 3-way handshake for making a connection. When a remote client connects to your TCP server, it sends SYN packet, and your server replies with SYN-ACK packet, then again that remote client sends ACK packet and then connection is established. So your application gets the connection when it is completely established. 
So Until your connection is half-done (I mean you have received SYN from a remote client and you have sent the SYN-ACK and you are waiting for last ACK), your application will not accept the connection. So there could be many remote clients trying to connect to your server and there could be many half-done connections in your listen queue.

I hope it explains the listen queue.

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong. (Example)If I have a listen queue of 5, and 9 clients are trying to connect(concurrently) to the server, 4 would be rejected. So, this queue specifies how many listen operations can be queued. And the number of threads is independent of this queue.

Comment: Yes you are right. If your queue limit is 5 and 5 or more connections are in-process of handshaking at server-end then next coming connections will be rejected. The number of thread is just on application level and this queue is in TCP drivers. The queue functions before your application/thread come to know about that incoming connection.

Comment: Actually, according to this: http://veithen.github.io/2014/01/01/how-tcp-backlog-works-in-linux.html that's not entirely true. But I haven't tried it myself. According to that article the client will  appear to make the connection even if the server has not placed it on the queue-of-things-that-can-be-accepted-by-the-application.